# Help identify components

Tags: capacitor, switches, identification, ups

This board is from a UPS. I was trying to remove the defective SA1 switch and accidentally broke one of the pins of the “J63” capacitor (its reference is C22 but it’s not showing).

[image: UPS board]

The board part number is this if it helps:

[image: part number]

What type is this square capacitor and how I can find its value? And if you know what kind of switch that was it would be helpful.

Comment: Does it have any other markings on any other side? Solder back the broken leg?

Comment: @winny no just the ones on top. i am going to try to solder it but unfortunately it broke right on the exit from the capacitor.

Comment: It's curious why these kind of polymer caps always seem to be rated for 63V. Makes me wonder what that magic number comes from... perhaps that would be a good separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a plastic film capacitor.

1J63 means 1 uF, 5%, 63 V.

Comment: just a regular capacitor; can i use a cylindrical one?

Comment: There are no regular capacitors, they all are special for their purpose. You must use a plastic capacitor, the shape will not matter. As long as it is not electrolytic or ceramic or tantalum or any other type, unless you know enough about the circuit to be able to safely change to a different capacitor.

Comment: @Justme I'm unfamiliar with the term 'plastic capacitor'; do you mean it's a film capacitor?

Comment: @Hearth Yes I seem to have forgotten  to type it. Thank you for spotting it.